# iOS in FBSDKShareDialog can we share without content

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I was going through Facebook docs from [FBLink](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/share-dialog), and searching api to make post through my app. But with the provided apis from Facebook i can see that we can post but needs to add content. e.g,

```
import FacebookShare

let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
    shareDialog.mode = .Native
    shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
    shareDialog.completion = { result in 
    // Handle share results
}

try shareDialog.show()
```

Can't we post without content?

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
var myContent = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/quynhbkhn")!)
        myContent.title = "share title";
        myContent.description = "share description";
        myContent.imageURL = URL(string: "https:yourimage.png")
        myContent.hashtag = Hashtag("#yourhashtag")
```